# Creating Custom Sized Tiles in Blank App -Win RT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

[image]

Hi , I am trying to create an blank app with my custom sized live tiles in the hub page. I know Windows had predefined tiles template ,but i was wondering if i could achieve the same with the existing tiles template or should i create an blank app .

Also if using a blank app ,can anybody tell me an resource where i can create the live tiles like in the image

Comment: are you talking about live tiles or tiles in a grid ? There is a difference. Live tiles come in certain dimensions and you cannot make custom sizes of them. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx for more on live tiles. If you're considering a gridview with variable size "tiles" you can implement this http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

Comment: i am talking about live tiles .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different concepts here:

- "Tiles" in your application's hub, **within the app**.  For this, you can either start with a predefined templates (like the Grid App in File-->New Project) or start from a Blank App and build your hub with its "tiles" from scratch.  In this scenario (tiles in a hub inside your application), there are no constraints on the sizes of the tiles, so you could create something like in your screenshot.
- Tiles **on the Start Screen**.  Your application will be represented by a tile on the start menu.  The concept of "live tiles" is dynamically changing the content in that tile in the start menu.  For that, you have to use the [predefined set of tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761491.aspx), and there are only two sizes of tiles available (the square tile and the wide tile).  More info on developing for live tiles [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/20/real-world-live-tiles-working-with-live-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jennifer ,thanks for your answer. I need "Tiles" in my Application's Hub ,within the app. I would like to start from scratch from blank app. Is there any resource online which can guide me in building live tiles from scratch in this blank app, as i want in the above image?   Also , which is more preferred -creating grid app from existing template or creating my own tiles using blank app?Thanks.

Comment: Neither method is preferred (starting from blank app vs. modifying grid app); it is whatever is easiest for you.  The article/video pointed out by danielovich above is great (I upvoted it!): http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html.  Use a control called VariableSizedWrapGrid to create differently-sized "tiles" in your hub.